# Get property from Maven Dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have 2 projects, one is a webapp, one a jar. Both are projects in maven and the webapp uses the jar as a dependency. I recently implemented the buildnumber-maven-plugin in both so now each have a ${buildNumber} property to reference the scm revision.

I have a UI that I show the versions of both and would like to show the revision number's as well as the version numbers. How can I get the ${buildNumber} property from the pom of the dependency from the main application?

Answer (score 0):

i would use maven to write in a properties file, and this file will be read by a servlet or something like that.

I've not tested it, but that's hint.
First, a properties file, in my war. 
This file contains :

```
version = ${project.version} //the value comes from maven
```

Secondely, 
a servlet or whatever server side (REST resource for example), that can read that property and communicate with the front

Thirdly, 
modifying the pom of the war like that :

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
<build>
```

Hope this help

Comment: got that already, that gets me to the dependency version, but not the revision #

Comment: my bad, so may be the end of this article might help http://blog.codehangover.com/track-every-build-number-with-maven/

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html)
The revision number is available using ${buildNumber} in your pom.

```
 <finalName>$\{project.artifactId}-r$\{buildNumber}</finalName>
```

To propagate it to the resources available to you app you can use instructions from vincent's answer.

Comment: same thing, that gets you the build number of the current app, but how about dependencies?

Comment: If you want to know the buildNumber of additional JAR inside the WAR you can have property file with buildNumber inside each JAR: jar1_version.properties, jar2_version.properties. Than in main war you can load them from classpath:                                                                       `String props[] = new String[]{"jar1_ver.props", "jar2_ver.props"};
        for (String p : Arrays.asList(props)) {
            Properties p1 = new Properties();
            p1.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(p));
            p1.get("version");    
        }`